# Change bash_profile path order

Tags: bash, command-line, .bash-profile

To use the right PHP version on my command line I want to change the `$PATH` of my command line profile.

For now, the command line uses the standard system php file located in `/usr/bin/`. I want to
use the php file from my zend server ce located in `/usr/local/zend/bin`.

I added `/usr/local/zend/bin` already to my bash_profile but it doesn't work because
when I print the `$PATH` variable, `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/local/zend/bin` and the terminal will takes the first one.

My PATH:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/zend/bin:/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin
```

I tried to update the .bash_profile file but it just include my 'zend' path's. Other path's look likes to set somewhere else or automatic?

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just prepend zend to your `PATH`

```
PATH=/usr/local/zend/bin:$PATH
```

Don't forget to reload or relogin.

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/zend/bin:$PATH
```